# How to display generic multi-series data in asp.net line chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have a database with several tables of data.  Each table has a completely different set of data.  The only similarity in each table is a ReadDate column that records the datetime that the data was written to the table.

For example Table1 would have these columns

- ReadDate
- Temperature
- Humidity

While Table2 would have these columns

- ReadDate
- Volume
- Ph
- FlowRate
- FlowRateSet

I'm attempting to build a web page (asp.net) that will allow the user to select a table and display the data in a line chart.  I need to be able to display the data by readdate across the chart but I can't seem to get any data to show up in the chart.

HTML

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" CssClass="chart" runat="server" Height="500px" Width="1500px">
   <Series>
      <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="0" YValueMembers="2">
      </asp:Series>
   </Series>
   <ChartAreas>
      <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
      </asp:ChartArea>
   </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

C#

```
// Clear any titles or data from previous queries
Chart1.Titles.Clear();
Chart1.Series.Clear();

// Display Chart Title
Chart1.Titles.Add(table.DisplayName);

// The following line returns a select statement specifically for the selected table.
// For example "select readdate, temperature, humidity from table1"
string query = data.SelectSQL;
DataSet ds;
using (DAL dal = new DAL())
{
   // The data access layer simply runs the query and returns a dataset.
   // In this example, the dataset returns with 16 rows of data.
   ds = dal.GetDataSet(query);
}

// Attempting to stuff the dataset into the chart.
Chart1.DataSource = ds;
```

I've added and removed code for the last several hours and have stripped it down to just this simple code above.  The end result of this code displays an empty chart with the name of the table at the top.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need to add series for each column name for which you want to show the line graph.
2. The best way to do this will be to, not hard code the series, but create each series during runtime. And if you want you can tie each series to the same chart area or you can create chart areas dynamically
3. Following code snippet. I have a data table having columns TIMESTAMP, OPEN, CLOSE, HIGH, LOW, VOLUME
4. TIMESTAMP is bound to X axis and other columns are bound to Y axis
5. User can select either or all of the columns and the code will show him line graph for each on the same chart area
6. Below code, chartarea1 is used to show dynamically calculated change percentage. chartarea2 is user to show OPEN, CLOSE, HIGH, LOW and candlestick graph and chartarea3 is use to show Volume using bar graph

```html
    <asp:Chart ID="chartAdvGraph" runat="server" CssClass="chart" Visible="false" BorderlineColor="Black" BorderlineDashStyle="Solid"
        EnableViewState="True" OnClick="chartAdvGraph_Click" ImageType="Png" ImageLocation="~/chartimg/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" ImageStorageMode="UseHttpHandler"
        OnPreRender="chart_PreRender">
        <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Name="legendAdvGraph" LegendItemOrder="SameAsSeriesOrder" Docking="Top" Alignment="Center" LegendStyle="Row"
                BorderDashStyle="Dash" BorderColor="Black" DockedToChartArea="NotSet" IsDockedInsideChartArea="false" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt">
                <Position X="0" Y="0" Height="3" Width="100" Auto="false" />
            </asp:Legend>
        </Legends>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="chartarea1" AlignmentOrientation="Vertical" AlignmentStyle="PlotPosition">
                <AxisX2 IsMarginVisible="false" IsLabelAutoFit="true" LabelAutoFitStyle="DecreaseFont" TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt">
                    <LabelStyle Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt" IsEndLabelVisible="true" />
                </AxisX2>
                <AxisY Title="Pct Change" TitleAlignment="Center" IsMarginVisible="false" IsLabelAutoFit="true" LabelAutoFitStyle="DecreaseFont"
                    TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt" IsStartedFromZero="false">
                    <LabelStyle Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt" Format="0.##"/>
                </AxisY>
            </asp:ChartArea>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="chartarea2" AlignWithChartArea="chartarea1" AlignmentOrientation="Vertical" AlignmentStyle="PlotPosition">
                <AxisX2 IsMarginVisible="false" IsLabelAutoFit="true" LabelAutoFitStyle="DecreaseFont" TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt">
                    <LabelStyle Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt" IsEndLabelVisible="true" />
                </AxisX2>
                <AxisY Title="Daily Index Value" TitleAlignment="Center" IsMarginVisible="false" IsLabelAutoFit="true" LabelAutoFitStyle="DecreaseFont"
                    TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt" IsStartedFromZero="false">
                    <LabelStyle Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt" Format="0.##"/>
                </AxisY>
            </asp:ChartArea>

            <asp:ChartArea Name="chartarea3" AlignWithChartArea="chartarea1" AlignmentOrientation="Vertical" AlignmentStyle="PlotPosition">
                <AxisX IsMarginVisible="false" IsLabelAutoFit="true" LabelAutoFitStyle="DecreaseFont" TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt">
                    <LabelStyle Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt" IsEndLabelVisible="true" />
                </AxisX>
                <AxisY Title="Volume" TitleAlignment="Center" IsMarginVisible="false" IsLabelAutoFit="true" LabelAutoFitStyle="DecreaseFont"
                    TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt" IsStartedFromZero="false">
                    <LabelStyle Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 8pt" />
                </AxisY>
            </asp:ChartArea>

        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
```

```js
public void ShowIndexGraph()
        {
            DataTable dailyData = null;
            StockManager stockManager = new StockManager();

            string fromDate = Master.textboxFromDate.Text;

            string selectedindex = Master.ddlIndexList.SelectedValue;
            string selectedindexname = Master.ddlIndexList.SelectedValue;
            bool bIntraday = false;
            try
            {
                DateTime dateFrom = System.Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate);
                if (DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString().Equals(dateFrom.ToShortDateString()))
                {
                    bIntraday = true;
                    //in case of today we will need to make sure we set time interval to min. If caller did not send interval in mins then we will default to 5min
                    //dailyData = stockManager.GetStockPriceData(selectedindex, time_interval: "5m", fromDate: fromDate);
                    //dailyData = stockManager.GetIntraWithPctChange(selectedindex, time_interval: "1min", outputsize: "compact");
                    dailyData = stockManager.GetStockPriceData(selectedindex, outputsize: "Compact", time_interval: "1m", fromDate: fromDate);
                    //Master.dropdownGraphList.Items[0].Enabled = true;
                    //Master.dropdownGraphList.Items[6].Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    dailyData = stockManager.GetStockPriceData(selectedindex, fromDate: fromDate);
                    //Master.dropdownGraphList.Items[0].Enabled = false;
                    //Master.dropdownGraphList.Items[6].Enabled = true;
                }

                if (chartAdvGraph.Annotations.Count > 0)
                    chartAdvGraph.Annotations.Clear();
                ViewState["MAIN_DATA"] = null;

                if ((dailyData != null) && (dailyData.Rows.Count > 0))
                {
                   GridViewData.DataSource = dailyData;
                    GridViewData.DataBind();

                    ViewState["MAIN_DATA"] = dailyData;

                    if (bIntraday)
                    {
                        chartAdvGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.LabelStyle.Format = "g";
                        chartAdvGraph.ChartAreas[1].AxisX2.LabelStyle.Format = "g";
                        chartAdvGraph.ChartAreas[2].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "g";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chartAdvGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.LabelStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
                        chartAdvGraph.ChartAreas[1].AxisX2.LabelStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
                        chartAdvGraph.ChartAreas[2].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
                    }


                    if (chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("Open") != null)
                    {
                        chartAdvGraph.Series.Remove(chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("Open"));
                    }

                    chartAdvGraph.Series.Add("Open");

                    if (chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("High") != null)
                    {
                        chartAdvGraph.Series.Remove(chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("High"));
                    }
                    chartAdvGraph.Series.Add("High");

                    if (chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("Low") != null)
                    {
                        chartAdvGraph.Series.Remove(chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("Low"));
                    }
                    chartAdvGraph.Series.Add("Low");

                    if (chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("Close") != null)
                    {
                        chartAdvGraph.Series.Remove(chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("Close"));
                    }
                    chartAdvGraph.Series.Add("Close");

                    if (chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("OHLC") != null)
                    {
                        chartAdvGraph.Series.Remove(chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("OHLC"));
                    }
                    chartAdvGraph.Series.Add("OHLC");

                    if (chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("Volume") != null)
                    {
                        chartAdvGraph.Series.Remove(chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("Volume"));
                    }
                    chartAdvGraph.Series.Add("Volume");


                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].Enabled = false;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].ChartArea = "chartarea2";
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].Legend = "legendAdvGraph";
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].LegendText = "Open";

                    chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].Enabled = false;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].ChartArea = "chartarea2";
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].Legend = "legendAdvGraph";
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].LegendText = "High";

                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].Enabled = false;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].ChartArea = "chartarea2";
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].Legend = "legendAdvGraph";
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].LegendText = "Low";

                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].Enabled = false;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].ChartArea = "chartarea2";
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].Legend = "legendAdvGraph";
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].LegendText = "Close";

                    chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].Enabled = true;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Candlestick;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].ChartArea = "chartarea2";
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].Legend = "legendAdvGraph";
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].LegendText = "Candlestick";
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].CustomProperties = "PriceDownColor=Blue, ShowOpenClose=Both, PriceUpColor=Red, OpenCloseStyle=Traingle";

                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].Enabled = true;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].XAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].ChartArea = "chartarea3";
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].Legend = "legendAdvGraph";
                    chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].LegendText = "Volume";

                    if (bIntraday)
                    {
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].XValueMember = "TIMESTAMP";// "latestDay";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].YValueMembers = "Open";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].ToolTip = "Date:#VALX{g}; Open:#VALY";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].PostBackValue = "Open," + selectedindexname + ",#VALX{g},#VALY";

                        chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].XValueMember = "TIMESTAMP";// "latestDay";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].YValueMembers = "High";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].ToolTip = "Date:#VALX{g}; High:#VALY";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].PostBackValue = "High," + selectedindexname + ",#VALX{g},#VALY";

                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].XValueMember = "TIMESTAMP";// "latestDay";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].YValueMembers = "Low";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].ToolTip = "Date:#VALX{g}; Low:#VALY";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].PostBackValue = "Low," + selectedindexname + ",#VALX{g},#VALY";

                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].XValueMember = "TIMESTAMP";// "latestDay";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].YValueMembers = "CLOSE"; // "Price";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].ToolTip = "Date:#VALX{g}; Close:#VALY";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].PostBackValue = "Close," + selectedindexname + ",#VALX{g},#VALY";

                        chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].XValueMember = "TIMESTAMP";// "latestDay";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].YValueMembers = "High,Low,Open,Close";// "High,Low,Open,Price";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].ToolTip = "Date:#VALX{g}; Open:#VALY3; High:#VALY1; Low:#VALY2; Close:#VALY4";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].PostBackValue = "OHLC," + selectedindexname + ",#VALX{g},#VALY1,#VALY2,#VALY3,#VALY4";

                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].XValueMember = "TIMESTAMP";// "latestDay";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].YValueMembers = "Volume";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].ToolTip = "Date:#VALX{g}; Volume:#VALY";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].PostBackValue = "Volume," + selectedindexname + ",#VALX{g},#VALY";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].XValueMember = "TIMESTAMP";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].YValueMembers = "OPEN";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].ToolTip = "Date:#VALX; Open:#VALY";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Open"].PostBackValue = "Open," + selectedindexname + ",#VALX,#VALY";

                        chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].XValueMember = "TIMESTAMP";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].YValueMembers = "HIGH";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].ToolTip = "Date:#VALX; High:#VALY";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["High"].PostBackValue = "High," + selectedindexname + ",#VALX,#VALY";

                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].XValueMember = "TIMESTAMP";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].YValueMembers = "LOW";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].ToolTip = "Date:#VALX; Low:#VALY";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Low"].PostBackValue = "Low," + selectedindexname + ",#VALX,#VALY";

                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].XValueMember = "TIMESTAMP";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].YValueMembers = "CLOSE";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].ToolTip = "Date:#VALX; Close:#VALY";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Close"].PostBackValue = "Close," + selectedindexname + ",#VALX,#VALY";

                        chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].XValueMember = "TIMESTAMP";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].YValueMembers = "HIGH,LOW,OPEN,CLOSE";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].ToolTip = "Date:#VALX; Open:#VALY3; High:#VALY1; Low:#VALY2; Close:#VALY4";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["OHLC"].PostBackValue = "OHLC," + selectedindexname + ",#VALX,#VALY1,#VALY2,#VALY3,#VALY4";

                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].XValueMember = "TIMESTAMP";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].YValueMembers = "VOLUME";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].ToolTip = "Date:#VALX; Volume:#VALY";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].PostBackValue = "Volume," + selectedindexname + ",#VALX,#VALY";
                    }

                    if (chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("PctChange") != null)
                    {
                        chartAdvGraph.Series.Remove(chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("PctChange"));
                    }
                    //chartAdvGraph.ChartAreas[0].Visible = false;
                    chartAdvGraph.ChartAreas[0].Visible = true;
                    chartAdvGraph.Series.Add("PctChange");
                    if (bIntraday)
                    {
                        //chartAdvGraph.ChartAreas[0].Visible = true;
                        //chartAdvGraph.Series.Add("PctChange");
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].Enabled = true;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].ChartArea = "chartarea1";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].Legend = "legendAdvGraph";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].LegendText = "Change";

                        chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("PctChange").Enabled = true;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].XValueMember = "TIMESTAMP";// "latestDay";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].YValuesPerPoint = 3;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].YValueMembers = "CHANGE_PCT,CHANGE,PREV_CLOSE"; // "changePercent";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Auto;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].ToolTip = "Date:#VALX{g}; Prev Close:#VALY3, Change%:#VALY1, Change:#VALY2";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].PostBackValue = "PctChange," + selectedindexname + ",#VALX{g},#VALY1,#VALY2,#VALY3";

                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].Enabled = false;
                        chartAdvGraph.ChartAreas[2].Visible = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].Enabled = true;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].ChartArea = "chartarea1";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].Legend = "legendAdvGraph";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].LegendText = "Change";

                        chartAdvGraph.Series.FindByName("PctChange").Enabled = true;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].XValueMember = "TIMESTAMP";// "latestDay";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].YValuesPerPoint = 3;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].YValueMembers = "CHANGE_PCT,CHANGE,PREV_CLOSE"; // "changePercent";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Auto;
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].ToolTip = "Date:#VALX; Prev Close:#VALY3, Change%:#VALY1, Change:#VALY2";
                        chartAdvGraph.Series["PctChange"].PostBackValue = "PctChange," + selectedindexname + ",#VALX,#VALY1,#VALY2,#VALY3";


                        chartAdvGraph.Series["Volume"].Enabled = true;
                        chartAdvGraph.ChartAreas[2].Visible = true;
                    }

                    chartAdvGraph.DataSource = dailyData;
                    chartAdvGraph.DataBind();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "myScript", "alert('" + ex.Message + "');", true);
            }
        }
```